# Angular2 routing with lazy loading child route issue

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

1. I have module called employment module
2. I have 2 routes "employee/edit/1" and "candidate/edit/1"
3. The route "employee" and "candidate" both route to the 'employment module'
4. Now I have 2 child route "edit/:id" and "edit/:id" both of which have same urls but must route to different component
5. Is there a way where I differentiate these 2 child route by their parent route without having to create 2 separate modules

Parent Routes:

```
      {
       path: "employee",
       loadChildren: () => require('./employment.module')['EmployementModule']);

     },
     {
      path:"candidate",
      loadChildren: () => require('./employment.module')['EmployementModule']);
     }
```

Child Routes:

```
    {
     path: "edit/:id",
     component: EmployeeComponent
    },

    {
     path: "edit/:id",
     component: CandidateComponent
    },
```

Comment: i think you should create routing file for both modules. each module has own routing file may help you out
bcz right now you have same url with on same module which is not allowed
so you should create seperate routing file for EmployeeComponent module and CandidateComponent, this why you can lazyload both modules completely

Comment: Even if I create two route files both file will be  **imported** by **EmployeeModule**  which then will be same as writing it in single file

Comment: nope you should create two module employee and candidate and both has its own routing file